# Implementing FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm struggling with how to do this correctly. I have the following activities in a stack like this;

A->B->C->D->E

When E finishes, I want to go back to B, destroying C,D,E in the process. I want to go back to the same instance of B, not instantiating a new version of it. In the activity E, I have this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

where LoginActivity is what I am calling activity B. The code branches to activity B, but I don't think that I am doing this correctly. I say this for two reasons:

1. I set a breakpoint in the `onNewIntent()` method of activity B, which is supposed to fire when starting the activity in this way. However, I never see this breakpoint.
2. I have a button listener on activity B. If I click this button when the stack originates from A->B, it fires just fine. However, when my flow is A->B->C->D->E->B the listener no longer fires. That is actually my bigger issue, but both of these pieces of information combined tell me that I have something wrong.

In fact, I can see from some logging output, that when I return to activity B, its `onCreate()` method is called, which is exactly what I am trying to avoid.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: In general your approach is correct and it should work as you expect. There is something strange going on. When Activity B starts Activity C, does Activity B call `finish()`? Please also add some logging in `onDestroy()` of Activity B and find out when this method is being called.

Comment: Thanks for this. You're right. There was something else going on. I had a broadcast receiver that wasn't implemented correctly, which caused my code to go into an exception state that I wasn't handling. Somehow that resulted in the startActivity not clearing the stack, but instantiating a new activity. Once I cleaned that up, it fell into place.

Answer (score 4):

> Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
>   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
>   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); startActivity(intent);

this will clear your back stack and restart LoginActivity.

you can do one thing. from B activity start all your activity with         `startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);

and when you do finish from E, finsish with setResult like this

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

so that you can catch all the back actions in `onActivityResult` in preceding activities that are D, C, and B(it will be your last).

and this will be your `onActivityResult` code below

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1) {
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

even i wanted to finish all preceding activities without restarting any activity and i had to end up doing like this. hope this helps you too

Comment: Thanks. This is a good suggestion, and the one that makes the most sense to me. In researching this, I found other posts that seemed to suggest that using Android's [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) was the preferable approach. However, I'm having trouble with it, as you can see. I'm going to see if someone has a solution that uses this approach. If not, I'll accept your answer, since I know that it will work. I already upvoted it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just getting back to this, and wanted to give some feedback because I liked your answer. However, I can't accept it as a solution. Here's why: It turns out that the code that I posted was actually correct, and that this approach is not only simpler, but also what Android recommends. (my problem was coming from an incorrectly implemented broadcast receiver, which threw me into an exception state that I hadn't noticed during debugging). So, while your solution will work, it requires extra code in each activity on the stack, where the Tasks and Back Stack approach only requires this one extra...

Comment: ...line to set a flag in the intent. Future readers of this can choose the method that they prefer. Thank you again!